# OperationalError at /admin/users/profile/ no such column: users_profile.bio

Tags: python, django

I'm following a tutorial on Django in Python, I'm trying to add a bio to my user profile page, however I get this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/users/profile/
no such column: users_profile.bio
```

Here is my models.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.TextField(User)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Here is my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Profile)
```

Comment: Did you run [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#workflow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change def __str(self):

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user.user)
```

**OR**

```
 def __str__(self):
        return 'Check if it is the problem'
```

Answer (score 0):

in models.py
change user to text,
like this

```
class Profile(models.Model):
text = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
bio = models.TextField(User)


def __str__(self):
    return self.text.username

cmd

"python manage.py makemigrations & 
python manage.py migrate "
```

are very important

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py sqlmigrate <user appname> <given number like 0001>
```

this worked for me